# Custom Page Layout for a publishing site with contents

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

I have a requirement of creating a custom page layout for my SharePoint 2010 users. What they want is, when they apply a page layout, they want the page to be filled with certain text in the rich content area. Some sort of template as they mentioned. Once they create the page with the layout, they will add extra contents to the page.

I don't know such a requirement can be achieved without writing C# code. 
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any C# code to do this.

Just create a standard page layout (for example, in SharePoint Designer) but include your sample text that you require within the controls' contents.

Here's an example, but there are many more on the internet, just search 'SharePoint 2010 custom page layouts sharepoint designer'

http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Comment: Thanks James. I am able to create a normal page layout with SPD, but I am looking for the content area to pre-populated with some text every time a page is created with the layout.

Answer (score 1):

For example if your publishing page is an enterprise wiki page edit the enterprisewiki.aspx page in sharepoint designer. than edit this part :

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="PageContent" FieldName="PublishingPageContent"
                 AllowTables="true" AllowEmbedding="true"
```

and add the html element

```
html="<p>this text will be displayed on every page</p>"
```

This way text you put in the html element will be displayed on every page.